# Azure data Factory save CSV from URL

Tags: azure-data-factory

I need to download a CSV file from a URL using Azure Data Factory v2.

The URL is: https://api.worldtradingdata.com/api/v1/history?symbol=SNAP&output=csv&sort=newest&api_token=demo

Do you know how to do this. I was thinking about downloading it to Blob storage but am unsure what connection to use?

Thanks,
Bob

Answer (score 2):

This is easy thanks to the HTTP connector, here is a tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-http

The tutorial guides you in creating a linked service, a dataset for that linked service and finally do a copy activity using that dataset!!

Should be fairly easy to follow, but if you have any questions be sure to reply me and ask away!

Hope this helped!