# Source must be binary when sink is binary dataset

Tags: azure, rest, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse, azure-data-lake-gen2

I am trying to download a csv file(the api returns a csv file, not a json) from web page, and store it in the data lake gen 2. So I created linked service for the webpage, dataset for the webpage, there seems no where for me to specify the file type of the data source. And then I created the linked service with ADLS2, also the dataset for ADLS2, with binary format.

When I try to run it by pressing debug, it gives me the error message:

```
Copy data1
Source must be binary when sink is binary dataset.
```

[image: source dataset image]

[image: source Linked Service image]
So I wonder how does the system knows that the source is not a binary dataset, and how can I do to resolve this

Thanks

Comment: It means when you created the Dataset for the web page (HTTP?) you selected something other than Binary. Can you show the Source Dataset configuration?

Comment: Thanks! I have added images for the dataset and linked service used in the source data

Comment: I can't tell from the screen shots what the underlying data type is. When you create an HTTP Dataset, it asks you what kind of data you are referencing (Delimited, JSON, Binary, etc.) If that is anything other than Binary, then you can't use it as a Source that writes to another Binary Dataset. Binary is limited in that both sides of the activity must be defined as Binary.

Comment: When using Binary dataset in copy activity, you can only copy from Binary dataset to Binary dataset. Can you try using HTTP connecter and select binary dataset in source? Please let me know if this works. Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58993778/azure-data-factory-save-csv-from-url

Comment: @Bruce - Are you able to work this out?

Comment: Thanks, I think with the HTTP connecter it worked

Comment: Hi @Bruce, Glad this worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Note**: When using Binary dataset in copy activity, you can only copy from Binary dataset to Binary dataset.

It throws an error if you are using `REST linked service` to copy binary source data to  sink as binary as we don't have options to select type of dataset.

[image]

Instead, you can use `HTTP connector` type and select the binary dataset from the options to copy binary data.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for sharing your knowledge. I had the same issue. Your suggestion resolved it.

Comment: Thanks for this.  ADF is such a strange animal.